# iPhone provisioning

Tags: xcode, ios-provisioning

I have an iPhone that is provisioned for distribution (ad hoc) only, for testing. It is not included in a development provision, but is included in an ad-hoc provision.

Why is it I can plug this iPhone into Xcode and run my app on it from Xcode? The Xcode scheme has "Run" set to "Debug." Doesn't this require a developer provision?

If not, then what is the difference between a development device provision and an ad-hoc provision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about 2 scenarios:

1. **Ad-hoc Provision**: The device that uses this method does not require to connect to development Mac. Only IPA and mobile provision certificate are needed to run the App. This method is mainly for client to test.
2. **Development Provision**: The device has to connect to Mac (at least once) to run the App. Debug session will be enabled and logs will be shown in debug console of xCode, when clicking "Run".

Note: A device can use both provision methods.

Comment: I understand this. My question is about why an ad-hoc provision provide development functionality, about connecting and running directly from Xcode in Debug mode? Isn't this a Development provision feature only?

Comment: Once you connect your device to Mac, you are in Development provision and the device will be added to Team Provisioning Profile.